# How to post from laravel form to external php?

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I have a php file for database entry called `db_insert.php`. I need to post info from laravel form to that php file. Everything worked if I had the db_insert file on a another server and linked to it directly. Now I need to keep all the files together and link to the db_insert file but when doing that I get a not found error. My guess is I need to point to the file somehow in laravel, maybe in the routes?

`$.post("https://test.com/test/db_insert.php", $("#desktop-form").serialize(),` this is the entry that worked. Now I moved the db_insert.php to my laravel prject root(because I don't know where else to put it) and linked to it like this: `$.post("../../db_insert.php", $("#desktop-form").serialize(),` and I get error `https://test.mysite.com/db_insert.php not found`

PS! this linking is done in `scripts.js` inside `myproject/public/js`

My question is where exactly would I put external php files like that in my laravel project and how exactly would I link to them or use them?

This is my first laravel project and most of it was done by another person. Sorry if anything is confusing and feel free to ask for any clarification.

**SOLUTION**

Solution was to store my db_insert.php in the public folder and link to it like so: `/update/db_insert.php`. Thank you @Stephen for the solution and I do unserstand this is a bad way to do things inside laravel but for this project I simply don't have the time to do it properly.

Comment: I think db_insert.php inserts data in database. You should use proper mvc and move your code to controller and make route for it.

Comment: If you're using a framework like Laravel, then you should really try to understand the framework and use it to its full advantage.  Laravel is designed in such a way that you don't need external PHP files for things like form submission.  It has a whole $request method built into its own controllers.  It's really, really, not a difficult framework to learn and you'll feel 1000x better about yourself and your applications if you give it a go.

Comment: @AbhijeetKambli thank you for the response. Unfortunately I have time constraints and since I'm new to laravel and MVC altogether I think I need to do it the wrong way this time and post to that db_insert.php because it would just take too long for me to do it the proper way. I will look into doing it as a controller but I'll keep the question open.

Comment: @Stephen I definitely understand what you're saying and I am learning it but for this project I was just pushed into it and need to fix a couple of things. I need to finish this particular project up quickly and don't have time to learn how to do it properly this time around.

Comment: @tillinips12 if needs must, create a folder under public for your file and then call it directly from your form. Ie, put it in public/update/db_insert.php and then <form method="POST" action="/update/db_insert.php"> , or via your AJAX $.post("/update/db_insert.php").  I cannot stress enough that this is not a great way to go about it though.